# Targeting specific div on specific WooCommerce product pages to customize css

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am using Wordpress and WooCommerce to build a website for my client. For every product page I have set up two groups of links (buttons, secondary menu) to allow user to visit other product category pages. I would like certain links to be automatically a specific color and weight when the user is on a certain product page (like an active state, but without having to first clicked on the link, I guess similar to breadcrumbs to show where the user is in terms of what category/categories the product they're viewing belongs to).

I've been trying to target the post-id and the div of the specific links to make css changes, but it's not working. I would really appreciate any help!

Here is the css I used to target a specific secondary menu link:

```
#menu-item-1886 > a {
color: #003b59 !important;   
font-weight: 600;
```

}

This works, but of course it made the change to this menu item across all pages. I want it to be only on a specific product page.

I also tried this, which also didn't work:

```
.body.post-id-766 #menu-item-1886 > a {
color: #003b59 !important;   
font-weight: 600;
```

}

The site is at http://www.hoptri.d-gecko.com

Again, really would appreciate your help with this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The pages on the site where I want to target are the individual product pages, for example this page (http://hoptri.d-gecko.com/vi/http:/hoptri.d-gecko.com/san-pham/autopot-hoptri-dualtray/)

Comment: This will not work for target body: ".body.post-id-766 #menu-item-1886 > a "
This will "body.post-id-766 #menu-item-1886 > a "
Notice the ".body" vs "body" ? There is your problem. :)

Comment: Thanks rgdesign, I tried this, but it's still not affecting the link. Is it possible that I need to include a parent div in the css?

Comment: Hey rgdesign, I took your correction and changed "post-id" to "postid" and it worked! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add with **`body_class`** WordPress filter hook  and choosen conditional tags some additional classes where you want, like in this example:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'adding_some_custom_body_classes' );
function adding_some_custom_body_classes( $classes ) {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        $classes[] = 'product-single-pages';
    } elseif( is_product() && is_single( array( 17, 19, 1, 11 ) )  {
        $classes[] = 'product-single-pages-2';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works

---

So you will be able to use that classes selectors in your CSS rules like (fake example):

```css
body.product-single-pages #menu-item-1886 > a,
body.product-single-pages2 #menu-item-1886 > a { font-weight: 600; }

body.product-single-pages #menu-item-1886 > a { color: green !important; }

body.product-single-pages2 #menu-item-1886 > a { color: red !important;  }
```

---

WooCommerce inject yet in body classes some specific classes as in this html example:

```
 <body class="product-template-default single single-product postid-19 logged-in woocommerce woocommerce-page right-sidebar woocommerce-active customize-support">
```

So you can also use this class selectors in your css:

- single-product
- woocommerce
- woocommerce-page
- woocommerce-active

For example this way:

```css
body.woocommerce.single-product.woocommerce-active #menu-item-1886 > a {
     color: blue !important; 
}
```

---

**References to conditional tags:**

- [Wordpress conditional tags list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)
- [WooCommerce conditional tags list](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, this solution worked perfectly!